# Adding Option to Choose Time Zone in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, timezone

I am working with a simple HTML page.

Users who live in different time zones should have the option to choose theirs. Then, a countdown clock will update to that time zone.

I have already created a dropdown menu with styles, but I am thinking that I would need to include more JavaScript to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Here is what I have currently...

**CSS:**

```
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 20px;
            border:none;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none; 
            position: absolute;
            background-color: black;
            min-width: 50px;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover { 
            background-color: white;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: grey;
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
            <button class="dropbtn">Select time zone...</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a timeZoneId="63" gmtAdjustment="GMT+07:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="7">(GMT+07:00) Krasnoyarsk</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="64" gmtAdjustment="GMT+08:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="8">(GMT+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="65" gmtAdjustment="GMT+08:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="8">(GMT+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="66" gmtAdjustment="GMT+08:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="8">(GMT+08:00) Irkutsk, Ulaan Bataar</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="67" gmtAdjustment="GMT+08:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="8">(GMT+08:00) Perth</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="68" gmtAdjustment="GMT+08:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="8">(GMT+08:00) Taipei</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="69" gmtAdjustment="GMT+09:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="9">(GMT+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="70" gmtAdjustment="GMT+09:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="9">(GMT+09:00) Seoul</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="71" gmtAdjustment="GMT+09:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="9">(GMT+09:00) Yakutsk</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="72" gmtAdjustment="GMT+09:30" useDaylightTime="0" value="9.5">(GMT+09:30) Adelaide</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="73" gmtAdjustment="GMT+09:30" useDaylightTime="0" value="9.5">(GMT+09:30) Darwin</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="74" gmtAdjustment="GMT+10:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="10">(GMT+10:00) Brisbane</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="75" gmtAdjustment="GMT+10:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="10">(GMT+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="76" gmtAdjustment="GMT+10:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="10">(GMT+10:00) Hobart</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="77" gmtAdjustment="GMT+10:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="10">(GMT+10:00) Guam, Port Moresby</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="78" gmtAdjustment="GMT+10:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="10">(GMT+10:00) Vladivostok</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="79" gmtAdjustment="GMT+11:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="11">(GMT+11:00) Magadan, Solomon Is., New Caledonia</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="80" gmtAdjustment="GMT+12:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="12">(GMT+12:00) Auckland, Wellington</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="81" gmtAdjustment="GMT+12:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="12">(GMT+12:00) Fiji, Kamchatka, Marshall Is.</a>
                    <a timeZoneId="82" gmtAdjustment="GMT+13:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="13">(GMT+13:00) Nuku'alofa</a>
                </div>
        </div>
```

**Countdown Clock JS:**

```
<script>
                var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 1, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
                var x = setInterval(function() {
                // get current date
                var now = new Date().getTime();

                // subtract count date from current date   
                var distance = countDownDate - now;

                // calculate days, hours, minues, seconds, miliseconds
                var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                // call element   
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + ":" + hours + ":"
                + minutes + ":" + seconds;

                if (distance < 0) {
                    clearInterval(x);
                    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Happy New Year!";
                    }
                }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi.  Time zones don't work the way that your list implies.  Please read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the sections titled "Time Zone != Offset" and "Time Zone Databases".  Also, you don't show in your question how exactly you'd like the time zone to impact the code (you aren't using any of the fields from the dropdown at all).  I assume you're looking for proper time zone support for your first line of code.  If so, you'll need a library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz).

Answer (score 0):

Once you select a certain timezone. You can catch the value of hours added and create a function to add extra hours:

```js
var value = 7;
//setting addHours function
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
    this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}

//append function at the end your object construction
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 1, 2020 00:00:00").addHours(value).getTime();
console.log(countDownDate);
```